# How/Where to discuss a best design strategy?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, best-practices

I'm primarily a web developer (Cold Fusion / HTML, JS, CSS etc).

I want to develop a part of my application that will be written in coldfusion. It's a scoring system and, much like this site (coincidentally), certain privileges are unlocked at certain thresholds.

The system will be written in cold fusion, but the cf community isn't very large, so I'd honestly welcome a bit more feedback on the method to do it. I can handle the code itself.

Would such a question perhaps belong in Programmers?

I'm not sure that it really counts as a 'best practice' question, since I'm not talking about things like properly naming variables, or thread-locking, or table schema.

I do have a few ideas in mind, but this isn't the site for going into question details. I know that the best questions show effort on the part of the asker and not just a "Do this for me!", so when I ask, wherever I ask, I'll list out the ways I see for doing it and the pros and cons that I see for each.

So, while I provided details for the question I want to ask, this question boils down to: **Where should a person ask about the best method to achieve something?**

Comment: Best Design Strategy isn't really a question.  How about you go research design strategies, and if you have questions about what you learn, ask those?

Comment: Sounds too broad as it is.  "How should I design this" isn't appropriate, really.  If you have a specific question about a specific design, *that* could belong somewhere, probably Programmers.